# Python преобразовать строку в список по разделителю

Tags: python, список

Как в Python преобразовать строку в список по разделителю ","
Если внутри части строки есть запятая, то эта часть строки выделяется двойными кавычки

Например, строку:

> данные, "данные, внутри которых есть запятая", "в этих ""данных, есть
> и запятая"" и кавычки"

преобразовать в список:

```
['данные', '"данные, внутри которых есть запятая"', '"в этих ""данных, есть и запятая"" и кавычки"']
```

Comment: А кавычки точно сбалансированы ? т.е. не надо учитывать запятые после нечетного количества кавычек или как ? И кстати, какие подходы вы уже пробовали для решения

Comment: Пробовал так: re.split(', (?![\w\.\s]+",)', my_string) - это работает, если внутри части есть запятая, но нет кавычек

Comment: `(?:[^"]*"")*[^"]*"|"[^"]*"|[^,"]+(?=,)`

Comment: Двойные кавычки внутри строки должны быть преобразованы в одинарные?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если из текста убрать пробелы после разделяющих запятых, получится вполне себе формат csv "стандартного" диалекта.

```py
import csv
import io

text = 'данные,"данные, внутри которых есть запятая","в этих ""данных, есть и запятая"" и кавычки"'

with io.StringIO(text) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        break
```

```
['данные', 'данные, внутри которых есть запятая', 'в этих "данных, есть и запятая" и кавычки']
```

Comment: Отличная идея делегировать разбор кавычек тому инструменту, который это умеет из коробки )

Comment: "Если из текста убрать пробелы после разделяющих запятых" - достаточно добавить параметр skipinitialspace=True, т.е. получилось так - reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True). skipinitialspace - когда True, пробел сразу после разделителя игнорируется

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так вот попробовать:

```
result = []
data = 'данные', '"данные, внутри которых есть запятая"', '"в этих ""данных, есть и запятая"" и кавычки"'

for d in data:
    if "," in d:
        sp = d.split(",")
        for s in sp:
            result.append(s)
    else:
        result.append(d)

print(result)
```

Вывод: 
['данные', '"данные', ' внутри которых есть запятая"', '"в этих ""данных', ' есть и запятая"" и кавычки"']

Если брать в том виде, что у вас, то при присвоении текста в переменную это будет кортеж. И таким образом, ничего в коде не измениться, а всего лишь надо убрать скобки.

Answer (score 0):

Регулярное выражение `, |"` ищет в строке кавычки и разделители. Флаг `quoted` означает "в кавычках", его надо переворачивать каждый раз когда видим кавычку. Если флаг сброшен и нашлась запятая её координаты складываются в список разрезов - `cuts`. В начало списка вставлен разрез в начале строки, в конец списка добавляется конец строки. В списке разрезов чётное число элементов. Каждая последовательная пара элементов указывает кусок текста, который попадёт в ответ:

```
import re


text = 'данные, "данные, внутри которых есть запятая", "в этих ""данных, есть и запятая"" и кавычки"'

print(text)
cuts = [0]
quoted = False
for m in re.finditer(', |"', text):
    if m.group(0) == '"':
        quoted = not quoted
        print('quote', m.span(), quoted)
    elif not quoted:
        cuts.extend(m.span())
        print('unquoted comma', m.span())
cuts.append(len(text))
print("cuts", cuts)

it = iter(cuts)
for f, t in zip(it, it):
    print(f, t, text[f:t])
```

> ```
> $ python parse.py
> данные, "данные, внутри которых есть запятая", "в этих ""данных, есть и запятая"" и кавычки"
> unquoted comma (6, 8)
> quote (8, 9) True
> quote (44, 45) False
> unquoted comma (45, 47)
> quote (47, 48) True
> quote (55, 56) False
> quote (56, 57) True
> quote (79, 80) False
> quote (80, 81) True
> quote (91, 92) False
> cuts [0, 6, 8, 45, 47, 92]
> 0 6 данные
> 8 45 "данные, внутри которых есть запятая"
> 47 92 "в этих ""данных, есть и запятая"" и кавычки"
> ```